# extract unique urls from a pool of urls

Tags: php

I have a list of urls in a text file just like below. I want to extract unique url patters, for example,

```
http://abi.sitename.org/aaa/4468488240.html
http://sss.sitename.org/aaa/4460627166.html
http://abo.sitename.org/aaa/4462471529.html
http://aby.sitename.org/aaa/4467495766.html
http://abz.sitename.org/aaa/4419425396.html
```

Is it possible to done with php? Please suggest.

```
http://abi.sitename.org/aaa/4468488240.html
http://abi.sitename.org/aaa/4462744311.html
http://abi.sitename.org/aaa/4419879366.html
http://sss.sitename.org/aaa/4460627166.html
http://sss.sitename.org/aaa/4456802709.html
http://sss.sitename.org/aaa/4425163148.html
http://abo.sitename.org/aaa/4462471529.html
http://abo.sitename.org/aaa/4469067299.html
http://abo.sitename.org/aaa/4453989838.html
http://aby.sitename.org/aaa/4467495766.html
http://aby.sitename.org/aaa/4454567635.html
http://aby.sitename.org/aaa/4466553375.html
http://abz.sitename.org/aaa/4457930202.html
http://abz.sitename.org/aaa/4419425396.html
http://abz.sitename.org/aaa/4455620614.html
http://abc.sitename.org/aaa/4459281546.html
http://abc.sitename.org/aaa/4458913064.html
```

Comment: create an array and use any of php's given unique sorter methods

Answer (score 0):

Load into an array and make it unique:

```
$lines = array_unique(file('/path/to/file.txt'));
```